# Mysql select one record from group having one of three conditions

Tags: mysql, sql

Using MySQL. I need to extract one record per group of storeID + profitCenter according to the following conditions:

1) If group has a single active record (active=1), select that record

2) If group has no active records select the most recent (max(id))

3) If group has multiple active records, select the most recent active record

Sample table:
(blank lines added for clarity)

```
 ID  | storeID | profitCenter | active
 --------------------------------------
 1   | X       | 1            |    1
 2   | X       | 1            |    0
 3   | X       | 1            |    0

 4   | X       | 2            |    0
 5   | X       | 2            |    1

 6   | X       | 3            |    0
 7   | X       | 3            |    0
 8   | X       | 3            |    0

 9   | X       | 4            |    1
10   | X       | 4            |    1
11   | X       | 4            |    0

12   | X       | 5            |    1

13   | X       | 6            |    0
```

Desired result:

```
 ID  | storeID | profitCenter | active
------------------------------------------ 
 1   | X       | 1            |    1
 5   | X       | 2            |    1
 8   | X       | 3            |    0
10   | X       | 4            |    1
12   | X       | 5            |    1
13   | X       | 6            |    0
```

A single query would be great but I'm thinking I'll need to do this in a stored procedure due to its complexity. I would need to write the records to a new table so I can use that in joins and such. So far all I've really got is...

...A simple query to pull the "single" records like so....

```
 SELECT * FROM table GROUP BY storeID, profitCenter HAVING count(*) = 1 AND active = 1
UNION
SELECT * FROM table GROUP BY storeID, profitCenter HAVING count(*) = 1 AND active = 0
```

...which yields...

```
 ID  | storeID | profitCenter | active
------------------------------------------ 
12   | X       | 5            |    1
13   | X       | 6            |    0
```

Then I can do...

```
 SELECT sum(active),tmult.* FROM
      (SELECT t.* FROM t LEFT JOIN
           (SELECT t.* FROM t GROUP BY storeID, profitCenter HAVING count(*) = 1 AND active = 1
      UNION
           SELECT t.* FROM t GROUP BY storeID, profitCenter HAVING count(*) = 1 AND active = 0) tsing
      ON t.id = tsing.id
      WHERE tsing.id IS NULL) tmult
 GROUP BY storeid, profitCenter
 HAVING sum(active)=1;
```

...which gives the active record for each group that has only one active record:

```
 ID  | storeID | profitCenter | active
 --------------------------------------
 1   | X       | 1            |    1
 5   | X       | 2            |    1
```

It's the groups that have either no active records or multiple active records that I can't even begin to figure out.

Am I taking the right approach? Should I even be attempting this in SQL? I could write a script to do it but I was hoping to not have to go that route.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: This is so extremely simple in other DBMS where you'd simply rank your records with `ROW_NUMBER` and so difficult (or clumsy at least) in MySQL. I suppose this is one of the reasons people switch from MySQL to MariaDB. Maybe an option for you, too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe something like this should do it:

```
 select 
    ifnull(max(active_records.id), max(all_records.id)) id,
    all_records.store_id,
    all_records.profit_center,
    if(max(active_records.id) is null, 0, 1) active
from
    store all_records
    left outer join store active_records on all_records.id = active_records.id and active_records.active = 1
group by
    all_records.store_id,
    all_records.profit_center
;
```

A full example with ddl and inserts is shown below:

```
create table store (
    id int,
    store_id varchar(64),
    profit_center int,
    active bit
);

insert into store values ( 1   , 'X'       , 1            ,    1);
insert into store values ( 2   , 'X'       , 1            ,    0);
insert into store values ( 3   , 'X'       , 1            ,    0);
insert into store values ( 4   , 'X'       , 2            ,    0);
insert into store values ( 5   , 'X'       , 2            ,    1);
insert into store values ( 6   , 'X'       , 3            ,    0);
insert into store values ( 7   , 'X'       , 3            ,    0);
insert into store values ( 8   , 'X'       , 3            ,    0);
insert into store values ( 9   , 'X'       , 4            ,    1);
insert into store values (10   , 'X'       , 4            ,    1);
insert into store values (11   , 'X'       , 4            ,    0);
insert into store values (12   , 'X'       , 5            ,    1);
insert into store values (13   , 'X'       , 6            ,    0);

select 
    ifnull(max(active_records.id), max(all_records.id)) id,
    all_records.store_id,
    all_records.profit_center,
    if(max(active_records.id) is null, 0, 1) active
from
    store all_records
    left outer join store active_records on all_records.id = active_records.id and active_records.active = 1
group by
    all_records.store_id,
    all_records.profit_center
;

+ ------- + ------------- + ------------------ + ----------- +
| id      | store_id      | profit_center      | active      |
+ ------- + ------------- + ------------------ + ----------- +
| 1       | X             | 1                  | 1           |
| 5       | X             | 2                  | 1           |
| 8       | X             | 3                  | 0           |
| 10      | X             | 4                  | 1           |
| 12      | X             | 5                  | 1           |
| 13      | X             | 6                  | 0           |
+ ------- + ------------- + ------------------ + ----------- +
6 rows
```

Comment: Original sql was incorrect and has been corrected.  This gives the result you are looking for.

Comment: Works perfectly. Any reason why you used ifnull(max(active_records.id)... for the ID field and then if(max(active_records.id) is null... for the ACTIVE field? Could you have used both interchangeably?

Comment: ifnull and if have slightly different syntax. It might be possible to use one or the other in both places.  The way I wrote it just seemed to make the most sense to me.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this with `union all`.

```
SELECT * 
FROM TABLE
WHERE (storeID, profitCenter, Id) IN (
SELECT storeID, profitCenter, MAX(case when active=1 then id end) as maxid
FROM table 
GROUP BY storeID, profitCenter
HAVING SUM(active) >= 1
UNION ALL
SELECT storeID, profitCenter, MAX(id)
FROM table 
GROUP BY storeID, profitCenter
HAVING SUM(active) = 0
)
```

Comment: Feedback: This appears to work but it takes nearly 30 seconds to run on approx 2300 records. Could be an indexing issue but John's solution runs almost instantaneously. Also, compared to John's solution, yours returns 4 less records. I have not taken the time to figure out what records are missing.